# How to write to a resource file?

Tags: c#, file, embedded-resource

If it is possible to read from a source file, like this:

```
string fileContent = Resources.Users;

using (var reader = new StringReader(fileContent))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] split = line.Split('|');
        string name = split[0];
        string last = split[1];

    }
}
```

Then how can you write to the same file?

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of the [ResourceWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) .
I'd also suggest that you make use of the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to read from the file.

Code from the link source:

```
using System;
using System.Resources;

public class WriteResources {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {

  // Creates a resource writer.
  IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("myResources.resources");

  // Adds resources to the resource writer.
  writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");

  writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");

  writer.AddResource("String 3", "Third String");

  // Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
  writer.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with including the salient content of an article you've linked to. In fact it makes your answer better in the long run because you never know when MSDN will change their urls

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    class Test {
  public static void Main() {
    ResourceWriter rw = new ResourceWriter("English.resources");
    rw.AddResource("Name", "Test");
    rw.AddResource("Ver", 1.0 );
    rw.AddResource("Author", "www.java2s.com");
    rw.Generate();
    rw.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thought the question was on how to write to a file. Your code seems to be displaying the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = @"c:\temp\contentfilelocation.extension"; //path to resource file location
if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
    // Create a file to write to.
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                string line = "<name>" + "|" + "<last>";
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I updated the code, path should be the location of the file you want to write to.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Resources;

using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@"D:\project\files\resourcefile.resx"))
                {
                    resx.AddResource("Key1", "Value");
                    resx.AddResource("Key2", "Value");
                    resx.AddResource("Key3", "Value");
                    
                    resx.Close();
                }
```