# How to save an instantiate spawning object when restart the game

Tags: c#

I want to keep my spawning object on my level editor when I restart the game, but I didnt figure out what is the problem.

I save my objects inside the `ToArray()`

and use the instantiate method to spawn it in game.

```
    this.levelData.objectSources = list.ToArray(); // save every objects 

    public T[] ToArray()
        {
            T[] array = new T[this._size];
            Array.Copy(this._items, array, this._size);
            return array;
        }

    //Instantiate to spawn the object that I want in the game
    GameObject gameObject = (GameObject)UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(Resources.Load("MyObject"));
```

So, the problem is, when I spawn the object in my level , I can play with it by using a `DontDestroyOnLoad`, but when I save the level then restart my game, the object is not here anymore.

Thank you if you know how to fix it

Comment: Restarting by pressing button in game (not shutting it down) or by shutting down and staring up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus so I save my level then restarting my game, but it wont save the instantiate object

Comment: Answer depends on what are you doing. If program itself is *not shutted down*, then i suggest you to make `static` element of your class type, inside your `GameObject` so you can refer to it even if the scene is redrawed. If your program *is shutted down*, then you have to serialize your `GameObject` into [program resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599662/how-to-write-to-a-resource-file) or hard drive and deserialize upon loading level.

Comment: Oh okay I understand I will check